# Woocommerce is trimming the last 0 from order_total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom woocommerce payment gateway, everything is working smoothly, I set the digits after decimals to two digits but whenever the price end with 0, order_total is being trimmed when its being sent to the gateway.

Example: if the amount is 122.98 the order_total go to the gateway as 122.98 but if the amount is 122.80 the order_total go to gateway as 122.8 and that is an issue with the gateway they need to receive a double digits after decimal even if double zeros. However the prices are showing well on the website the double digits is working well on site display only when it's sent to gateway the zeros disappear.

Gateway code below:
        /**
         * Get netcommerce Args for passing to netcommerce
        **/
        function get_netcommerce_args( $order ) {
            global $woocommerce;

```
        $order_id       = $order->id;
        $currencyUSD    ='840';
        $order_total    = $order->get_total();
        $merchantID     = $this->txtMerchNum;
        $notify_url     = add_query_arg( 'wc-api', 'wc_tbz_netcommerce_gateway', home_url( '/checkout' ) );

        $signature_elts =$order_total.$currencyUSD.$order_id.$this->txtMerchNum.$notify_url.$this->sha_key;
        $signature      =hash('sha256',(string)$signature_elts);

        // netcommerce Args
        $netcommerce_args = array(
            'txtIndex'              => $order_id,
            'txthttp'               => $notify_url,
            'txtAmount'             => $order_total,
            'txtCurrency'           => $currencyUSD,
            'txtMerchNum'           => $this->txtMerchNum,
            'payment_mode'          => $this->payment_mode,
            'first_name'            => $order->billing_first_name,
            'last_name'             => $order->billing_last_name,
            'email'                 => $order->billing_email,
            'mobile'                => $order->billing_phone,
            'address_line1'         => $order->billing_address_1,
            'address_line2'         => $order->billing_address_2,
            'postal_code'           => $order->billing_postcode,
            'city'                  => $order->billing_city,
            'state'                 => $order->billing_state,
            'country'               => $order->billing_country,
            'signature'             => $signature

        );

        $netcommerce_args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_netcommerce_args', $netcommerce_args );
        return $netcommerce_args;
    }


    /**
     * Generate the netcommerce Payment button link
    **/
    function generate_netcommerce_form( $order_id ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

        $netcommerce_adr = $this->gateway_link;

        $netcommerce_args = $this->get_netcommerce_args( $order );

        $netcommerce_args_array = array();

        foreach ($netcommerce_args as $key => $value) {
            $netcommerce_args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="'.esc_attr( $key ).'" value="'.esc_attr( $value ).'" />';
        }

        return '<form action="'.esc_url( $netcommerce_adr ).'" method="post" id="netcommerce_payment_form" target="_top">
                ' . implode('', $netcommerce_args_array) . '
                <input type="submit" class="button-alt" id="submit_netcommerce_payment_form" value="'.__('Make Payment', 'woocommerce').'" /> <a class="button cancel" href="'.esc_url( $order->get_cancel_order_url() ).'">'.__('Cancel order &amp; restore cart', 'woocommerce').'</a>
            </form>';

    }


    /**
     * Process the payment and return the result
    **/
    function process_payment( $order_id ) {

        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        return array(
            'result' => 'success',
            'redirect'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url( true )
        );
    }


    /**
     * Output for the order received page.
    **/
    function receipt_page( $order ) {
        echo '<p>'.__('Thank you for your order, please click the button below to make payment.', 'woocommerce').'</p>';
        echo $this->generate_netcommerce_form( $order );
    }


    /**
     * Verify a successful Payment!
    **/
    function check_netcommerce_response(){
        global $woocommerce;
        if(isset($_POST['txtIndex']))
        {


            $transaction_id = $_POST['txtIndex'];
            $order_id       = $_POST['txtIndex'];


            $order          = new WC_Order($order_id);
            $order_total    = $order->get_total();

            $amount_paid    = $_POST['txtAmount'];
            $RespVal        = $_POST['RespVal'];
            $RespMsg        = $_POST['RespMsg'];
            $txtMerchNum    = $_POST['txtMerchNum'];
            $txtNumAut      = $_POST['txtNumAut'];
            $Signature      = $_POST['signature'];

            $txtCurrency    = $_POST['txtCurrency'];
            $sha=$this->sha_key ;
            $SignatureElts=$txtMerchNum.$order_id.$amount_paid.$txtCurrency.$txtNumAut.$RespVal.$RespMsg.$sha;
            $ReturnSignature= hash('sha256',$SignatureElts);

            if($ReturnSignature != $Signature){
            $message1="Signature error" ;
            if ( function_exists( 'wc_add_notice' ) ) {
                        wc_add_notice( $message1, 'error' );

                    } else { // WC < 2.1
                        $woocommerce->add_error( $message1 );
                        $woocommerce->set_messages();
                    }
            }
```

Please advise
Thank you

Comment: Use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) with an empty string for the thousands separator.

Comment: I didn't quite understand you well... Woocommerce is showing prices well on site and even in the emails sent to client and admins the price include a 2 digits after decimal even if it was zeros. The only place the zeros are gone is when the amount is send to our gateway if there are zeros at the end, they will be gone

Comment: You'll need to include [the code which isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help with the problem.

Comment: Code is added, however the gateway is working only the $order_total is removing useless zeros from digits after decimal so instead of sending the amount total as 122.80 it's sending 122.8

Comment: What happens if you replace `'txtAmount'             => $order_total,` with `'txtAmount'             => number_format($order_total, 2, ".", ""),`?

Comment: It worked like a charm.. only had to replace $order_total with number_format($order_total, 2, ".", "") in the signature as well... Thank you a lot

Comment: I'll write it as an answer so you can accept it if you like. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$order_total = $order->get_total();` with `$order_total = number_format($order->get_total(), 2, ".", "")` to get a string padded to 2 decimal places instead of a float.